# Users with less than 2k reputation appear as reviewers

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I was looking into the [stackoverflow review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review).
It appears that something is wrong with the Suggested edit section. As per the other sections, it should display people who are reviewing these posts. But looks due to some issues that it is showing people whose posts has been suggested for edits.

To check this issue, just hover over the people, and you will see the people having much less reputation than the 2k appear in this queue.

> [image: user with 3 reputation has reviewed a suggested edit]

Comment: Any one can approve or reject the suggested edit on their own posts. You can see their review history in their reviews tab: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/<USERID>?tab=activity&sort=reviews`

Comment: If you approve the suggested edit I made to your post, you will appear in the recent reviewers list of the queue.  How meta is that?

Comment: @Arulkumar: we can directly edit our post..without any approval. I believe this criteria should not be included here in this scenarion

Comment: @StephenRauch: Yes, but to approve the post you at least need 2k reputation. and I cant see this condition meeting for many people for this queue

Comment: You should be able to approve the suggested edit on your own post.

Comment: @StephenRauch: Ok, I got it.

Comment: It has a lot to due with earning badges, there is first edit badge so you are bound to find someone just looking to edit something just to earn their badge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a post you submitted is put into the suggested edit queue, you're notified.  You can then accept or reject the suggested edit.  This action is recorded just as if you had reviewed the suggested edit from the queue, instead of because it was your own post.

Thus, you can see people in the recent reviewers list who are not generally eligible to be reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: So it means suppose I asked one question and you edited that. Now this question will go to the Suggested Edits review queue. I can approve or reject it even though I have less than 2k reputation because it has been asked by me. And once I perform the approve/reject task, my name will appear in that list. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, you are in the list right now at https://meta.stackexchange.com/review

Comment: OP in recently reviewed queue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYIRp.png

Comment: Yes, correct. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that it can be accepted with just your vote.